# Why Grafana duplicates legend on the dasboard but not in explorer mode?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

when playing with a query in explore mode Grafana builds the correct legend:

[image]

but when I use the same query on the dashboard as time-series graph legend is duplicated:

[image]

The Prometheus query I use:

```
sum (rate(ruby_http_requests_total{controller=~"api/v2/.*"} [5m])) by (status)
```

Is this a known bug? Why explore mode works fine?

Comment: Check returned data with query inspector - maybe some statuses have whitechars, maybe label values are mixing strings, integers - so that "duplication" is correct - they are different statuses and explore mode deduplicate time series. No source data, so it is only a guess.

Comment: Hey Jan, thank you for the suggestion. After looking a little bit more, I found that time series graphs with duplicated labels contain the correct data frame (eg samples for status == 200) and additional data frame with the latest value. It looks like Grafana is plotting the latest value separately.

This is true only for time series graphs embedded into the dashboard and query inspector working from this level. Doing the same operation from the level of "Explore" page does not yield this artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. In the "Options -> Type" I selected "Both". After changing to "Range" the issue has been fixed. "Explore" mode works correctly for any case.

[image]